# OpenGL - drawing blocks with different textures on each side

Tags: c, opengl, textures

I'm trying to create a block with multiple textures, one on each side of it,
the problem is I want to have 32x32 pixels on each side and an overall texture of 192x192 so I basically 'fold' that texture and then attach it to that block or cube or whatever.
I'm not sure how to do that, I googled it and I found the way to use sprite-sheets but do I really need to make it 6 different textures ?

Comment: Where does the 192x192 for the overall texture come from? If you combine the 32x32 for each side into a single texture, wouldn't 192x32 (or 96x64) be enough?

Comment: @RetoKoradi it's not just like wrapping it, it's like a 'box' of texture that the real box would be inside of it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If you wish to create a texture for a box which looks like an unfold, flatten box, you can do that, but it is not necessary, though it helps designer viewing things that way for more complex objects.